# ArcGIS License - ArcInfo level license set during python script execution vs via Desktop Administrator

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, geoprocessing, license

We have an ArcInfo floating license available.  Can I check out an ArcInfo level license via arcpy. [Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000z000000), from the arcgis help, it says you can import a license level for stand-alone scripts.

If a user has ArcView installed/running on their machine and they execute a custom script tool that requires ArcInfo licensing, in arcpy, can we browse to a floating license on a license server somewhere and set the product there.  I don't see any methods in the help.

Otherwise, is my only option to have the user close down all ArcGIS instances, navigate to Desktop Administrator, browse to the server, open ArcMap with ArcInfo and then run the script tool?  I would like to avoid this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the sample script in the CheckProduct section? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003r000000

Comment: I did not because I would have to get onto some one else machine for testing as I have ArcInfo on my machine.  I don't see any argument for server path similar to how it looks in Desktop Administrator.  I can try it and report back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check this help file out.
[Accessing Licenses and extensions in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000z000000)

The *CheckProduct(code)* and *SetProduct(code)* methods look like they will provide you with the tools you're looking for.

Comment: I looked at that but it doesn't show how you would reference a network server running license manager.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It should just work as long as the license manager is set up in Desktop Administrator.

Comment: This is totally the way to go, and like blah238 says, so long as they have the Desktop Admin pointing to your license server, they should be good to go. Make sure  you not only programmatically check out the license, but check it back in after you are done with it.

Comment: Any thoughts on "Legacy" status? I try to "import arcinfo" first. It makes sense now that I hear you guys saying it. Just have to visit each machine and make sure they have pulled an arcinfo license at least once. Thanks.

Comment: I believe one key point that I think has been missed, which leads me to believe what the user wants is not available through this method.  Note that in the link provided above, the tip states: _The setting of the product and extensions is only necessary within stand-alone scripts. **If you are running tools from the Python window or using script tools, the product is already set from within the application**, and the active extensions are based on the Extensions dialog box._

Comment: @RyanDalton thanks.  How about calling a script on local user machine that calls a python gp service that yields the data somehow over to the local python script being run.  This would useful for running/testing scripts locally that will be executed by the server in production.

Comment: @RyanDalton Great point.  I suspect this is by design b/c if you could import ArcInfo from there then you could just create 'custom' tools for every esri ArcInfo tool.  It would be a very efficient way to use an ArcInfo license, perhaps too efficient for esri's taste.